# Mongo Query Optimization for collection over 10 Million records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, query-optimization

I have a collection with over 10 Million records, I need to match with a particular field and get
the distinct _ids of the records set.

after the $match pipeline the result set becomes less than 5 Million.
if i group with id to get the unique ids, the execution time on my local environment is over 20 seconds.

```
db.getCollection('viewscounts').aggregate(
[
   {
       $match: {
           MODULE_ID: 4, 
       }
   },
   {
       $group: {
           _id: '$ITEM_ID',
       }
   }
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

- If I get rid of either $match or $group and have only 1 pipeline, the execution time is less than 0.1 seconds.

I'm okay with limiting the _ids, but they should be unique.

Can anyone suggest a better way to get the results faster?

Comment: Can you explain what the variable and condition `VIEWED_DATE: 3 === 3` is and for what it is used for?

Comment: Hi @hhharsha36 don't worry about that, its a conditional match, that case is added to get into the true path for testing purposes. I've removed the entire statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have already implemented the best Aggregation pipelines possible for the query to get your desired output.

The reason why your query results are faster when using only one of the aggregation pipelines is that the query result returns partial output instead of the entire 5 million records. where when you add both the stages, the entire output of the `$match` stage has to be processed by `$group` stage resulting in more time.

The only way to optimize your aggregation query is to apply indexes on `MODULE_ID` and `ITEM_ID` keys

```
db.viewscounts.createIndex({MODULE_ID: 1}, { sparse: true })
db.viewscounts.createIndex({ITEM_ID: 1})
```

It should be faster after you perform the above two indexes on your `viewscounts` collection.

Additionally, you can also get your desired output from MongoDB distinct command. Give the below query a try and see if it helps.

```
db.getCollection('viewscounts').distinct("ITEM_ID", {"MODULE_ID": 4})
```

> Note: The above query returns an array of unique key-values instead of objects like in the aggregation query

Hope this helps

Comment: Do u know any other approaches than the normal aggregation to handle this large collection, eg:- big data approaches or sharded DB.

Comment: Except for the `distinct` operation, I don't think there is any other approach. Being a rookie, I may be wrong here